# DACPAC deployment fails on EXTERNAL DATA SOURCEd schemas

Tags: sql, dacpac

(Here is a problem with a similar issue:
[Publish to SQL Azure fails with 'Cannot drop the external data source' message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40652256/publish-to-sql-azure-fails-with-cannot-drop-the-external-data-source-message))

There is this new pattern called Sql Db Elastic Query (Azure).

The gist of it is captured here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-elastic-query-overview

Now, I have a SqlProj that defines:

- External Data Source (EDS) and
- Database Scoped Credentials (DSC)

To prevent passwords being in the script (I am using SqlCmd variables)

I probably have a gazillion views on "external" tables, based on the elastic query pattern.

And during DACPAC deployments to SQL Azure, I always get an error on:

```
Error SQL72014: .Net SqlClient Data Provider: Msg 33165, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 Cannot drop the external data source 'XXXX' because it is used by an external table.
Error SQL72045: Script execution error.  The executed script:
DROP EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE [XXXX];
```

Checking the logs, I realize that there are all these Views/Tables that exist and use these EDS/DSC combo.

The work around comes with a price that's ever deepening.
So the question is, has anyone else hit this problem and found the root cause of this?